# Add content to the end of each (non-whitespace) line in string in python 3

Tags: python, regex, string, replace

Suppose I have the following string:

```
s = 'some text\n\nsome other text'
```

I now want to add the letter 'X' to the end of each line containing text so that the output is `'some textX\n\nsome other textX'`. I tried

```
re.sub('((?!\S)$)', 'X', s, re.M)
```

but that only adds `'X'` at the end of the string even though it is in multiline mode, i.e., the output is `'some text\n\nsome other textX'`. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really need regex? You could just split on newlines, add `X` accordingly, and re-join. Here's one way of doing it, using `yield` -

```
In [504]: def f(s):
     ...:     for l in s.splitlines():
     ...:         yield l + ('X' if l else '')
     ...:         

In [505]: '\n'.join(list(f(s)))
Out[505]: 'some textX\n\nsome other textX'
```

Here's an alternative using a list comprehension -

```
In [506]: '\n'.join([x + 'X' if x else '' for x in s.splitlines()])
Out[506]: 'some textX\n\nsome other textX'
```

---

For reference, this is how you'd do this with regex -

```
Out[507]: re.sub(r'(?<=\S)(?=\n|$)', r'X', s, re.M)
Out[507]: 'some textX\n\nsome other textX'
```

You need to use a look-ahead as well as a look-behind. Here's a breakdown of the expression -

```
(?<=    # lookbehind
\S      # anything that is not a whitespace character, alt - `[^\n]`
)
(?=     # lookahead
\n      # newline
|       # regex OR
$       # end of line
)
```